# Shiny calling a reactive in another reactive. Error: could not find data

Tags: r, aggregate, shiny

I am having trouble using Shiny to perform a reactive on another reactive to be used in another reactive. I have `pdata` to subset data and I want to use send that `pdata()` to `zdata()`. `Zdata` will perform aggregation on this `pdata()` and I want to send this aggregated data to `ggplot`. But Shiny is saying:

> ERROR: could not find function "pdata".

Here is the data frame:

```
Hours<-c(2,3,4,2,1,1,3)
Project<-c("a","b","b","a","a","b","a")
Period<-c("2014-11-22","2014-11-23","2014-11-24","2014-11-22", "2014-11-23", "2014-11-23", "2014-11-24")
cd=data.frame(Project,Hours,Period)
```

### Server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(doBy)
library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  pdata <- reactive({
    subset(cd, Project==input$proj)
  }
  )
  zdata<-reactive({
summaryBy(pdata()$Hours ~ pdata()$Period, data = pdata(), FUN=sum )
  })
  plotType <- reactive({
    switch(input$pType,
           Total = ggplot(zdata(),aes(x=Period,y=zdata()[2]))+ geom_line()+stat_smooth()
           )
      })
  output$testPlot <- renderPlot({ 
    print(plotType())
```

})

---

I am confident my `ui.R` is right so I didn't post. I started getting errors with the line:

```
summaryBy(pdata()$Hours ~ pdata()$Period, data = pdata(), FUN=sum )
```

Why is Shiny giving me error: could not find function `pdata`?

Comment: `pdata` is defined within a function and therefore it is only stored in the function's environment. You need to either `return pdata` from the function into a variable or evaluate `pdata` in the second reactive with `eval` (although the second might be tricky with shiny). Or you could also try `pdata <<- reactive......` to define it globally and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pdata() seems redundant in the formula... Could you try this code?

```
zdata<-reactive({
  summaryBy(Hours ~ Period, data = pdata(), FUN=sum )
})
```

Comment: This appears to be right. However, now I get error: could not find function zdata().                                       Total = ggplot(zdata(),aes(x=Period,y=zdata()[,2]))+ geom_line().                                                  It's my y-variable. I'm trying to call the second column. Do you know if I'm calling the y-data correctly.

Comment: I used y=zdata()[,2] because I do not know the column name that the previous reactive returns. I only know that its the second column I want

Comment: I would suggest to create a new data frame df <- z[,c(1,2)] in zdata(). Then, you can make something colnames(df) <- c('x','y') and use df in ggplot(df) + aes(x=x,y=y) + ...

Comment: NOTE: above worked. However, the following also worked: ggplot(zdata(),aes(x=Period,y=Hours.sum))+geom_line()